# Error C2662 issue

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I am doing some program, and so far so good when it's about implementation, however now I am stuck with trivial problem, but I am in no position to find a solution for it. The problem is in this part of the code, and it say

> Error 1   error C2662: 'Smetler::action' : cannot convert 'this' pointer from 'const Smetler' to 'Smetler &'

Anyone knows what's the problem here is, since I am sure I applied all what it was been said.

```
  virtual void action()
  {
    std::cout << "I'm a copy" << copy() << ". Doing observations." << std::endl;
  }      
  Smetler* copy() const { return new Smetler (*this); }     
   private:
   void writeDown(ostream& wd) const                            
   { 
      wd << Worker::getOccupation() << " " << Worker::getName() << ',' <<  Worker::getPosition()  << action(); 
   }
   };
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all, you meant to write `return new Smetler (*this);` Also, this is NOT a good programming style. You will definitely get memory leaks sooner or later. Use smart pointers!

Comment: Also, you didn't supply relevant piece of code.

Comment: Yep, it was mistake done while writing it here . It's about 3000 lines of code, the thing is he weeps about it here, so I have posted that part of the code.

Comment: @Serenity Stack Holder: What line number does the `C2662` refer to, exactly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<strike>You have this:</strike>

```
Smetler* copy() const { return new Smetler* (*this); }
```

This doesn't allocate a `Smetler` object. It allocates a pointer of type `Smetler`. You're attempting to convert a `const Smetler&` (which is the type of `*this` in `const` functions) to a `Smetler*`, which of course doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

What you probably want is this:

```
Smetler* copy() const { return new Smetler(*this); }
```

The above will allocate a new `Smetler` on the free store and copies the `this` object into the new space. You have to `delete` the returned pointer eventually to avoid memory leaks.

What you really want is to use a smart pointer so you won't have to worry about `delete`-ing the returned pointer from `copy()`. In C++03, you can use `std::auto_ptr` (although it has been deprecated since it can accidentally be used in an unsafe situation e.g. you can't use `auto_ptr`s in containers like `std::vector`):

```
std::auto_ptr<Smetler> copy() const
{
    return std::auto_ptr<Smetler>(new Smetler(*this));
}
```

Or, if you can use C++11, use the much more superior `std::unique_ptr` which doesn't have any of `auto_ptr`'s problems.

```
std::unique_ptr<Smetler> copy() const
{
    return std::unique_ptr<Smetler>(new Smetler(*this));
}
```

Both the above code snippets will help a long way with preventing memory leaks (and not having to worry about them in the first place!)

Comment: Yes, it was misspell while writing here, that's what I have been truly writing. Thing about smart pointer is nice, so I will try it. :)

Comment: Thanks that's exactly what I have been looking for. :)